# how to append the list using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, web, append

Basically, i try to append a list using jquery. Each element in this list is connected to a different link. This is what i done

```
for (i=0; i <data.length ; i++ ){

        var a = $('<a />');
        a.attr('href','https://example.com/browse/' + data[i].key);
        a.text(data[i].name);


        $("#list-of-project ul").append("<li>").append(a).append("</li>");


    }
```

"data" here is an JSON array i get from REST having key and name attribute.
However, using this , i got output like this [unwanted result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqEdO.png). The element not at the same line with the list points.
I want the text to be at the same line with the list points. Any help??

Answer (score 2):

```
for (i=0; i <data.length ; i++ ){

    var a = $('<a />');
    a.attr('href','https://example.com/browse/' + data[i].key);
    a.text(data[i].name);
    var li ="<li>"+a+"</li>"
    $("#list-of-project ul").append( li );
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] and elaborate your answer. Code only answers hard to understand for the future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

You can't append partial elements, like just opening and closing LI tags.
Create the LI element first, then append the anchor to it, then append it to the UL

```
for (i=0; i <data.length ; i++ ){

    var a = $('<a />', { 
        href : 'https://example.com/browse/' + data[i].key,
        text : data[i].name
    });

    var li = $('<li />');

    $("#list-of-project ul").append( li.append(a) );
}
```

Note that if `data` has many indices, you should do the appending outside the loop, and append all the elements at once

Comment: best answer imo because of creating the link in one step with parameter object

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to append the open and closing tags like you are doing, simple append the `a` to the `li`, then append the `li` to the `ul`...

```
for (i=0; i <data.length ; i++ ) {
    var a = $('<a />');
    a.attr('href','https://example.com/browse/' + data[i].key);
    a.text(data[i].name);

    var li = $('<li/>');
    li.append(a);

    $('#list-of-project ul').append(li);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="test" id="inputName" />
<button id="btnName">Click me!</button>

<ul class="justList"></ul>

$('#btnName').click(function(){
    var text = $('#inputName').val();
    if(text.length){
        $('<li />', {html: text}).appendTo('ul.justList')
    }
});
```